# Rank of a module when the base ring is not a domain

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Suppose $R$ is a commutative Noetherian local ring with $1$, which is **not a domain**. Let $M$ be a (non-free) finite $R$-module. What is meant by rank of $M$ in this case?

Comment: If the ring $R$ is commutative with 1, isn't the rank the cardinality of a maximal $R$-linearly independent set in $M$? I don't see $R$ not being a domain changes this.

Comment: @msteve: the first thing that comes to my mind is how does one show that (when $R$ is not a domain) the number you are referring to is finite? And why would any two maximal $R$-linearly independent sets in $M$ have the same cardinality?

Answer (score 2):

The paper that I am reading assumes rank of a module always exists. Hence, it may be using a different definition of rank, which may (or may not) coincide with the definition provided in the previous answer, when $M\otimes_RQ$ is free over $Q$. After I posted my question I found the following definition of rank in the book [Syzygies](http://books.google.com/books?id=NjW5Ka5M0L4C&pg=PP8&dq=Syzygies&hl=en&sa=X&ei=b5LaU6aoHMilyATy84Fw&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=Syzygies&f=false) (By E. Graham Evans, Phillip Griffith) on page 2:

Rank of $M$ = maximum of {rank of $M/\mathfrak{p}M$ over $R/\mathfrak{p}$, where $\mathfrak{p}$ runs over the set of minimal prime ideals of $R$}.